# Are votes on comments now part of the daily total?

Tags: support, voting, comment-voting

From time to time, I run out of votes for the day.  When this happens, I am usually able to continue voting on comments without a problem.

When I went to upvote a comment in the last few minutes, the standard "Daily vote limit reached" box popped up.

Is this new?  Have I just missed it in the past? (I checked the new features list and I couldn't find anything about it)

Comment: are you getting less than the full 30 votes during the day, or just not the full forty?

Comment: @jcolebrand I got the full 40.  When I've run out before, it hasn't seemed to effect the number of comment votes I could make, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The daily limit for the comment votes is separated from the daily limit for voting on questions and answers. It just happened that you reached both the limits.

Comment: Hehe, I suppose I should read fewer questions.  I had thought about that I might have reached some other limit simultaneously, but the timing of it was so close that I was sure it was related... Okay, thanks.

Comment: @jonsca It happened to me too, and asked on the EL&U meta site. That is how I know it. `:-)`